# Structure on disk in beginning of RAID 1 (first 128 MiB)

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid1

I have a RAID 1 consisting of 2 2 TB disks and noticed that when I compute the cryptographic hash of some range of both disks, unless that range is in the beginning of the disks, I get the same result. So anywhere but in the beginning (and some small part in the end where the partitions used for the RAID end, I guess), the 2 disks store exactly the same data.

However, in the beginning of the disks, the checksums don't match which means the data stored there deviates. I'd expect this to happen on the first few kilobytes because I'd expect data used for disk identification and some other metadata to be stored there. But what I find is that there is a mismatch on the first 128 MiB. If I only skip the first 127 MiB, the checksums don't match but if I skip the first 128 MiB and hash some range, the checksums do match.

What does `mdadm` store in the beginning of the disks which takes up so much storage space (as compared to just identifiers; of course compared to the size of modern hard disks, it's completely negligible)?

Note that I addressed the data from the beginning of the partitions used in the RAID. It's not that I addressed it from the beginning of the disks and the first 127 MiB just happen to not belong to the partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `mdadm --examine`, `Data Offset`. It tends to default to 128M if the partition is large enough. In everyday operation, the data offset is not used for anything.

Until you decide to grow the RAID or change the RAID level and layout. Then the data offset will be reduced by a bit, thus creating a buffer zone that allows to change data in place without directly overwriting itself. As such the process can be safely resumed in the event of a power loss, reboot, etc.

When no remaining data offset space is available, you are required to supply a `--backup-file` for some grow and reshape operations. This backup file must be stored outside of your RAID and must be able to survive reboots.

If you are very sure that you will never change the RAID layout, or don't mind the use of the backup file in that event, you can specify `--data-offset=` of a small 1 or 2 MiB and thus not waste 128M per drive.

Comment: For both partitions, the command prints `Data Offset : 262144 sectors` (which is exactly 128 MiB for 512 Byte sectors). As it is stated per partition constituting the array (if I pass the array device path, it only prints `mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/md1.`), can this value be different for different partitions or disks of the same array?

Comment: Although the data offset is usually the same across devices, it's entirely possible for it to be different. It's mentioned in the mdadm man page (last paragraph in the `--data-offset=` section, data offset can be specified as variable).

Comment: For people searching for information about what --data-offset refers to, it is the offset for each physical disk, not the resulting md device. That had me confused for a while.